# Tridion publishing triggering both targets

Tags: content-delivery, publishing, cme, 2013-sp1, content-manager

**Background**: SDL Tridion 2013 Clustered TCM - [2 nodes] / Deployer is using Apache Tomcat

**Situation**: When I publish to a single [non-prod] `publishing target`, I see my item proceed to publish successfully, as expected. However, when I choose the other [prod] target, then view the `publishing que`, I see that it is also pulling **both** targets for that item, then proceeds to publish successfully.

**Question**: Any insight on why when I choose a single specific target, it would choose the other and publish both simultaneously? Is there something I am missing or overlooked within the `cd_deployer_conf.xml` or `cd_storage_conf.xml`?

I cannot even figure out if it is on the CM (server configuration) or CD side based upon my troubleshooting..

*I have performed some troubleshooting, even shut down 1 deployer and specified a single url within the Admin of the CME instead of it being routed through a traffic manager. Still same issue..*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually select `Target Types` when you publish an item. The `Publication Target` is associated with one or more than one `Target Types` like "Live" or "Staging". 
To find the same:

Open the `publication target` in question in CME and then go to the `publication` tab. Look at the `Allowed Target Types`. If you have more than one `Target Types`, when you publish to any of them it will publish to this target as well.

Comment: To add to this, I've seen it done often to ensure all content published to Live is also published to Staging.

Comment: @NunoLinhares - a staging target within the production TCM within the prod environment vertical of DTAP or a staging target with the prod TCM that points to the stage/acceptance environment? Point being, so content is kept updated in lower environments - as its published live?

Comment: Obviously, there would be conflicts if any schema changes would be in flight and/or code for the next deployment per the same set of schemas and design with the vertical promotion of code..but you just made me think of a content demotion strategy with the last comment you made - possibly an entirely new question on SE in itself

Comment: I did mean a Staging Target within the Production TCM, as in the P of DTAP - the only objective being that you can't update Live without that same content ending up on Staging. Publishing to lower environments will get you into massive trouble due to TCM ID (possible) conflicts.